# How to use an XSLT to move data between XML nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I don't know a lot about xslt but I need to fix a bug in someone else's code.  The issue is that some data is not being outputted correctly in an XML file so I need to use an XSLT to move the data to the correct node.  An example is shown below:

Incorrect XML:

```
<record name="recordname" value="Text(AAxxxx)">
<field name="recordID" value=""/>
</record>
```

Correct XML:

```
<record name="recordname" value="Text(AAxxxx)">
    <field name="recordID" value="Text(AAxxxx)"/> 
    </record>
```

So I need to copy the value of the value field from the record name node to value in the field name node.  Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Extract "value" in XSLT is:

```
<xsl:value-of select="record/field/@value" />
```

Extract atribbute is "@" after of element.

this is a possibility.